# Big-O Order and Best Big-O order for f(n)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I have some questions about Big-O notation:

> 1  Find the Big-O notation for the following sum: $1^2 + 2^2 + ... n^2$
>
> 2  Find the best (i.e., lowest) Big-O order for $f(n)$, where $f(n) = 1 + 4 + 7 + ...(3n+1)$. Hint: the possible answers are arranged in the increasing order of growth.)

1. I have $O(n^3)$, $O(n^4)$, $O(n^6)$, $O(n^7)$ (these are the highest powers of $n$ the instructor has in the multiple choice question.)

I am totally lost on $2$. The choices are $O(1)$, $O(log(n))$, $O(n)$, $O(n^2)$, $O(n^3)$, $O(n^4)$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm thinking it may be O(n^2), O(n^3) and O(n^4), but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(n)$ is an $n^{th}$ degree polynomial, then $f(n) = \mathcal{O}(n)$. If we can find polynomial expressions for those sums, then we can use this fact to find a big-O bound for them. For the first one, it is well-known that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2 = 1^2 + 2^2 + ... n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

For the second, if we consider it as an arithmetic series with $a_1 = 1$ and $a_n = 3(n-1) + 1$(note that I've reindexed the sequence - yours has $a_0 = 1, a_n = 3n + 1$), we can use the formula for arithmetic series $S_n = \frac{n(a_1 + a_n)}{2}$ to find a closed-form expression for the sum:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} (3i + 1) = 1 + 4 + 7 + ...(3n+1) = \frac{n(3(n-1)+2)}{2}$$

Do you see how to proceed from here?

Comment: Explaining *how* you got the second sum would most likely help the OP much more.

Comment: I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @ComputerScienceStudent Added more detail - how about now?

Comment: I don't understand how the n's in the equation translate to the Big-O notation. I'm distributing the n's, and I get (3n^2-3n+2n)/2, but I don't see how that information can be used to solve the problem. @SplitInfinity

Comment: @ComputerScienceStudent
If $f(n)$ is an $n^{th}$ degree polynomial, then $f(n)=\mathcal{O}(n)$. This is the remaining piece of information you need to solve the problem.

Comment: So #2 would just be $O(n)$? Did I do the first one correctly?

Comment: Oh, I think I see now. Since the question asks for the lowest Big-O, the lowest value will always be the degree of $n$. Is that correct? @SplitInfinity

Comment: @ComputerScienceStudent Yes, that is correct. So the answer to #2 is not $O(n)$ like you previously stated.

Comment: And since #1 asks for the Big-O notation, not only the best one, it will be $O(n^3)$, $O(n^4)$, $O(n^6)$, and $O(n^7)$? ($O(n^2)$ is not a choice.) @SplitInfinity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36345/discussion-between-splitinfinity-and-computersciencestudent).

Comment: I just realized I may have misunderstood you about question 2. I was thinking that the answer was $O(n)$. I believe you were saying this is wrong. For #2, it should be $O(n^2)$, right? @SplitInfinity

Comment: @ComputerScienceStudent Yes.